# Get 2 parameters from a returning fuction (tuple) in python

Tags: python, parameters, tuples

I'm having difficulty getting two parameters returned from a function as a tuple:

```
>>> ir7(41,7)

(966, 1023, 571, 396, 105, 2, 3)
```

If I want to get specified tuple I use this:

```
 >>> ir7(41,7)[0]

966
```

but what if I want to get 1st, 3rd and 4th element from the tuple. What is the correct syntax? Something like:

```
a,b,c= ir7(41,7)[1][3][4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack the return values:

```
_, a, _, b, c, _, _ = ir(41, 7)
```

The `_` indicates the value being assigned here are not important.

Comment: I'm using micropython not sure how it is in normal python but here _ is variable name too, it use memory still. I was hoping that there was a direct syntax calling this, but looks there is no method for that

Comment: You could delete the `_` variable after. As written in other answers, manually choose the indexes you want by saving the result of the answer first.

Answer (score 1):

Call the method only once to make it more efficient. After that, it's just a matter of tuple-assignment.

```
v = ir7(41,7)
a, b, c= v[1], v[3], v[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `ir7(41,7)[1][3][4]` you essentially tries to get the 4:th element of the 3:rd element of the 1:st element of an object (basically a 4-dimensional list). Instead you should fetch them separately:

```
# Get all the values initially in a separate variable
values = ir7(41,7)
a, b, c = values[1], values[3], values[4]
```

Or I you can do it this way:

```
_, a, _ b, c = ir7(41,7)
```

By omitting the indexes you don't want with placeholder variables `_`

Answer (score 1):

There is a convention for using `_` as the name for variables that you don't actually want to use. Using this, you can do:

```
_, a, _, b, c = ir7(41, 7)
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
value = ir7(41, 7)
a, b, c = value[1], value[3], value[4]
```

If the number of items to exclude is large, you definitely want the second option.

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce slicing to slim the result down before assigning values as well:

```
a, _, b, c = ir7(41, 7)[1:4]
```

Even better you could use `operator.itemgetter`

```
from operator import itemgetter

a, b, c = itemgetter(1,3,4)(ir7(41, 7))
```